# What can cause Sprockets::CachedEnvironment error?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, tinymce, erb, centos6

My RoR application falls down with the following error:

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `attributes_for' for 
>   Sprockets::CachedEnvironment:0x00000005baf3d8

As I found out this error happens when the javascript in the html.erb template is rendering. Also I noticed that in all templates where it happens exists tinyMCE initialization command.

I suppose, that it is something environment specific, because at my development machine it works fine and at production server it also works fine. I began to receive this message when I decided to install 2nd production server for testing purposes. I installed CentOS 6 + rvm + ruby 2.2.0 (the same as at 1st production server). Maybe I missed to install something?

Comment: I've created a pull request https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails/pull/175 for sprockets 3 support. You can use forked version anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the problem is related to `tinymce` and `sprockets` I am guessing that you are using `tinymce-rails` GEM.

The `tinymce-rails` GEM does not work fine with `sprockets` >= 3. It is using some API that was removed in version 3.

If you still want to use `tinymce-rails` GEM, please lock `sprockets` to `~> 2`. This has solved problem for me.

The perfect solution would be to make a pull request for `tinymce-rails` to make it work with the latest `sprockets`, but that's whole nother story.